# Pyspark : convert string to foat for all the dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame that contains several columns (1000) and they have string type. I want to transform them to float not one column by one column but all the data frame at one time.

Furthermore, I know this exists:

```
 from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
 data_df = data_df.withColumn("column_name", data_df["columns_name"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

But I'm researching for something like this :

```
data_df = data_df.cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Column by column is the only way.

Comment: ok thank you but maybe when I read my csv file do you know if I can put an option or something like this

Comment: I'm using this : data_train = spark.read.option("delimiter" , ";").csv('matrice.csv' , header = True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your best option is to pre-select all columns into a list, then write a list comprehension with casting in a select.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, FloatType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

cols = df.columns
df.select(
  *[f.col(col).cast(IntegerType()).alias(col) for col in cols]
)
# for casting to float please replace with FloatType()
```

However, please be wary that `pyspark` will fail silently on `cast`, e.g. if one row of a column cannot be cast into the target type. This means that the entire column will return `NULL` if your `StringType` column cannot be cast to `IntegerType`.

Therefore I recommend you run some data validation tests to check your dataframe is populated as expected. Tools like `great_expectations` are great for this.